# Is it possible to count the number of different digits in a number recursively?

Tags: c#, count, digits

This is a code that counts the number of digits in a number recursively. What can I add to this code to count how many **different digits** are in a number? Or it has to be done some other way?

```
    int numberOfDigits(int n)
    {
       if(n == 0)
          return 0;
       else
          return numberOfDigits(n/10) + 1;
    }
```

Comment: "This is a code that counts digits in a number." is incorrect. Voting to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: Don't use random language tags (C# and C++), please.

Comment: `return n.ToString().Distinct().Count(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');`

Comment: Your edit is an improvement, but now this is a simple duplicate. Please search before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sets!

```
static int NumberOfDigits(int a) {
    return new HashSet<char>(Math.Abs(a).ToString()).Count;
}
```

We make `a` into a string and then turn the string into a set of characters. Since sets cannot contain duplicate values, the count of the set is the number of distinct digits.